# C++: Best Way To Hold Entity List vector vs set

Tags: c++, vector, entity

I have implemented an entity-component system to manage my entities in a game engine, managing components using std::map. Now the main part is to hold all entities in the CWorld class. Those entities can be directly accessed with index by CWorld, to add component etc. And also, all entities will be iterated each tick for update and render operations. And the list will not be static as you can guess, I mean entities can die, so need to be removed from list at some point. At this point, I need to ask the differences between std::vector and set, or any suggestion to hold entities.

Comment: Checking a [refernece](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the elements by index, and if old elements may die such that the range of active indices may contain gaps, then a map is probably the easiest solution. Map also allows you to iterate and remove single entities easily.

List is easy to remove a single entity but hard to look-up a specific entity by index.

Vector is difficult to remove a single entity without leaving gaps. By plugging the gap, the index of entities after the removal will change.

Answer (score 2):

While you would be better off asking this spin of this question on the [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange, I'll add this: STL only makes promises about scaling, it does not make promises about actual costs. O(1) is the right hand of an expression: "x = O(1)" where "O" is the cost of "an operation". "fopen" is an operation, that costs O(1). Is O(1) cheap?

You'll need to run perf analysis on your code and look at the specs for each of the classes - you may even need to write your own, since the STL containers are *generic* and not optimized for any specific usage case.

The thing to focus on is frequency of operations - read, write, manage. Assuming a tick is every 10ms, it seems unlikely that you are going to remove entities anywhere near as often as you walk the list. Are you implementing your own scenegraph? If so, the granularity is going to determine how often entities move between spaces, and that should be a factor in the patterns you employ: if the frequency of management overhead is sufficiently low, you can afford to have management structures that have a high cost, but will still want to avoid something that's O(N) unless O() is very, very cheap.